# Meeting room hardware for audio and video sharing

Tags: hdmi, video-adapters

I have to setup a meeting room, I'm going to buy a big TV, speakers, polycom phone and I want a recommendation about the video/audio sharing chance.

The first solution is a simple HDMI cable between the table and the TV/Speakers but I would like to know if exists some good wireless alternatives.

I saw **Airtame** but if possible I want to avoid the software installation on the PC, for example meeting guests don't want to install custom software in their devices.

I saw **Ubiq** but I don't like the internet approach, better to not be bound by network bandwidth. Not all guests are enabled to internet access.

Comment: I'm confused as to what "video/audio sharing chance" means. Do you mean how to connect device[s] to the TV/speakers? If so, what device[s] are you connecting? Where does the Polycom phone play into this?

Answer (score 1):

I have used ClickShare. They sell dongles that handle everything automatically. You pair it to your meeting room hardware and whoever has the dongle can share.

Comment: The question is very old, and finally I choosed ClickShare Barco. It is very expensive but I fully satisfied of the choice! Thanks for resurrecting this question!

Answer (score 0):

I am Zornitsa from Airtame.

We have a lot of customers who are using a Guest app for Windows for the cases, when they have guests without Admin right on their computers. You can download and save it to a USB an d place it in the meeting room. We also help with some easy guides that you can place in the room, as well as emails that you can send to your guests. Find the app here https://airtame.com/download. We would be happy to advise you more on your use case. You can find us here on our chat at the bottom right corner www.airtame.com.

Best,
Zornitsa